# wp_verify_nonce not working, whereas wp_create_nonce works

Tags: wordpress

I am surprised why wp_verify_nonce not working. It's showing undefined function error, my wordpress version is upto date. I am attaching my plugin code. Please help me

```
    add_shortcode('tw_safety_checklist_template','init_tw_safety_checklist');

    function init_tw_safety_checklist(){
        echo '<form method="post">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="tw_new_checklist_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce('tw_new_checklist_nonce').'"/>
            <input type="text" name="tw_name" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['tw_new_checklist_nonce'])){
        tw_create_my_template();            
    } 

    function tw_create_my_template(){
        if(wp_verify_nonce($_POST['tw_new_checklist_nonce'],'tw-new-checklist-nonce'))
        {
            return 'Worked!';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `wp_verify_nonce()` is a [pluggable](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions) function.  That means that it is not declared until after the plugins are loaded.  Since your `if` statement is loose in your file, it is being executed when your plugin loads; as such, `wp_verify_nonce()` (correctly) has not been declared yet.

You need to move your `if` statement into an [action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hooks:_Actions_and_Filters) using [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/).  Which hook will depend on exactly what the purpose of your `tw_create_my_template()` function is.  You'll want to do something like this:

```
add_action('init','tw_create_my_template');
function tw_create_my_template(){
    if( isset($_POST['tw_new_checklist_nonce']) 
      && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['tw_new_checklist_nonce'],'tw-new-checklist-nonce'))
    {
        return 'Worked!';
    }
}
```

Note, you'll want to replace `init` with whatever hook is appropriate for your function.  `init` is fairly typical for plugin initialization actions but the important thing is that it is something that happens after [`plugins_loaded`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/plugins_loaded).  You can find the list of typical actions, in order, [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

Answer (score 0):

Note also that you have an error in your code, you are creating the nonce with the action key `'tw_new_checklist_nonce'`,

```php
wp_create_nonce('tw_new_checklist_nonce')
```

but verifying it with the action key `'tw-new-checklist-nonce'`,

```php
wp_verify_nonce($_POST['tw_new_checklist_nonce'],'tw-new-checklist-nonce'))
```

you have to use identical action keys to validate your nonce.